# Unable to use splitterChannel with advanced xml configuration with poco

Tags: c++, xml, logging, configuration-files, poco-libraries

I would like to configure an advance logger using poco and its configuration file.
I create a config.xml file like that :

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<Application>
    <logging>
        <channels>
            <c1>
                <class>ColorConsoleChannel</class>
                <formatter>
                    <class>PatternFormatter</class>
                    <pattern>%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S : %s : [%p] : %t</pattern>
                </formatter>
                <traceColor>lightBlue</traceColor>
                <debugColor>blue</debugColor>
                <informationColor>green</informationColor>
                <noticeColor>green</noticeColor>
                <warningColor>yellow</warningColor>
                <errorColor>red</errorColor>
                <criticalColor>lightMagenta</criticalColor>
                <fatalColor>lightMagenta</fatalColor>       
            </c1>
            <c2>
                <class>FileChannel</class>
                <path>logs/traceApplication.log</path>
                <rotation>1 M</rotation>
                <archive>number</archive>
                <purgeCount>5</purgeCount>
                <formatter>
                    <class>PatternFormatter</class>
                    <pattern>%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S : %T : [%p] : %t</pattern>

                </formatter>
            </c2>
        </channels>
        <loggers>
            <consoleLogger>
                <channel>c1</channel>
                <level>information</level>
            </consoleLogger>
            <traceFileLogger>
                <channel>c2</channel>
                <level>trace</level>
            </traceFileLogger>
        </loggers>
        <channels>
            <cSplitter>
                <class>SplitterChannel</class>
                <channels>consoleLogger,traceFileLogger,mainFileLogger</channels>
            </cSplitter>
        </channels>
        <loggers>
            <root>
                <channel>cSplitter</channel>
                <level>trace</level>
            </root>
        </loggers>
    </logging>
</Application>
```

I use a Poco::Util::ServerApplication class and in the initialize method I put :

```
void CBS2AudioVideo::initialize(Poco::Util::Application& self)
{
    loadConfiguration("config.xml");
    Poco::Util::ServerApplication::initialize(self);
}
```

Before adding the splitterChannel my logging works well but with it, it doesn't any more.

I got the error message :

> Not found: logging channel: consoleLogger

My goal is to have only one root logger and when I use it, it log in information level into the console and in trace level into the file.

When I set channels in channels.cSplitter.channels it works but all channels are logged to the same level. And if I take the logging configuration slide (http://pocoproject.org/slides/185-LoggingConfiguration.pdf) they use loggers and not channels in the logging.channels.splitter.channels attribute area. So I think it is possible. More over the Logger class inherit from Channel too.

Someone has already done this kind of work or have an idea ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've finally found the solution.
I post it here if it interest someone.

This file works well.

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<Application>
    <logging>
        <channels>
            <cScreen>
                <class>ColorConsoleChannel</class>
                <formatter>
                    <class>PatternFormatter</class>
                    <pattern>%H:%M:%S : %T : [%p] : %t</pattern>
                </formatter>
                <traceColor>lightBlue</traceColor>
                <debugColor>blue</debugColor>
                <informationColor>white</informationColor>
                <noticeColor>green</noticeColor>
                <warningColor>yellow</warningColor>
                <errorColor>red</errorColor>
                <criticalColor>lightMagenta</criticalColor>
                <fatalColor>lightMagenta</fatalColor>       
            </cScreen>
            <cFile>
                <class>FileChannel</class>
                <path>logs/application.log</path>
                <rotation>1 M</rotation>
                <archive>number</archive>
                <purgeCount>5</purgeCount>
                <formatter>
                    <class>PatternFormatter</class>
                    <pattern>%H:%M:%S : %T : [%p] : %t</pattern>
                </formatter>
            </cFile>
        </channels>
        <loggers>
            <root>
                <name></name>
                <channel>cFile</channel>
                <level>trace</level>
            </root>
            <main>
                <name>main</name>
                <channel>cScreen</channel>
                <level>trace</level>
            </main>
        </loggers>
    </logging>
```

To log on the screen and in the file make :

```
Poco::Logger::get("main").trace(msg);
```

To log only into file make

```
Poco::Logger::get("").trace(msg);
```